# $httpProvider.interceptors with factory of another module

Tags: angularjs

I am developing one application with multiple modules. I am using service module and root module. I define a factory in service module. I am calling  `$httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptorService")` in root module. This line throwing error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authInterceptorServiceProvider <- authInterceptorService <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=authInterceptorServiceProvider%20%3C-%20authInterceptorService%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile
```

code :

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router','app.data'])
        .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$httpProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state("/", {
                url: "/",
                views: {
                    content: { templateUrl: "/Scripts/app/Views/Splash.html", controller: "SplashController" }
                }
            });
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptorService");
        }]);

--- Service module

 angular.module("app.data",[])
.factory("authInterceptorService", ["$q", "$injector", "localStorageService", function ($q, $injector, localStorageService) {

        var request = function (config) {

            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            var authData = localStorageService.get("authorizationData");
            if (authData) {
                config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + authData.token;
            }

            return config;
        }

        var responseError = function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                var stateService = $injector.get("$state");
                stateService.go("Login");
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
        var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {
            request: request,
            responseError : responseError
        };

        return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
    }]);
```

Comment: Deleted my original answer b/c I wasn't reading carefully.   I have not worked much with interceptors but I think you need to define the factory off the $provide.   (rather than as a standalone factory like you are doing)

Comment: Where does `localStorageService` come from? Also, is the code example you show from a single file or are the two module definitions in separate files? If they are in separate files, are you sure both are getting loaded?